# moving body whose deceleration is proportional to the square root of the velocity

Tags: calculus, integration

A body is moving  with velocity  16ft/sec when it is suddenly  subjected to a deceleration.  If the deceleration is proportional to the  square root of  the velocity ,  and the body comes to rest in 4 seconds,

a) how fast is the body moving two seconds after it begins decelerating ,

and b) how far does the body travel before  it comes to rest?

I've  done the following 
$a=k \sqrt {v}$
Where $k$ is the proportionality constant
 I substituted $v= 16ft/sec$ and integrated to get $v$ as a function of  time and integrated again to get the position function. But I couldn't  get the answers right.

Comment: You should post your work to avoid downvotes or votes to close. You should only have to integrate acceleration once to get velocity. Integrating twice gives position.

Comment: When I integrated  the deceleration function I got $v= 4kt+c$ from it but the problem is now I have two unknown constants

Comment: That's incorrect. You should have $\frac{dv}{dt}=k\sqrt{v}$. You must separate variables to integrate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{dv}{dt}=k\sqrt{v}\implies \int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{v}}dv}=\int{kdt}\implies 2\sqrt{v}=kt+C$.

At $t=0$ we are given that $v=16$ so $C=8$.

This gives $2\sqrt{v}=kt+8$. We know that $v=0$ at $t=4$ so we get $0=4k+8\implies k=-2$.

Therefore, we get that $2\sqrt{v}=-2t+8\implies v=\frac{(-2t+8)^2}{4}$.

We can integrate this to get position as a function of time and plug in $t=4$ to get the distance traveled before coming to rest.

When we integrate we get $x=\int_{0}^{4}{\frac{(-2t+8)^2}{4}dt}=\frac{-(-2t+8)^3}{24}$ evaluated from $0$ to $4$ which gives $x=0--\frac{64}{3}=21\frac{1}{3}$ feet.